# Oracle 12.1+ Update CLOB String Data With Null

Tags: json, oracle, sql-update, oracle12c, clob

I am using `Oracle 12.1+` DB and over the time of period some of data in my `table column` `COKE_INFO` of type `CLOB` gets corrupted.

I have corrected java code to not let that happen but for all historical data I want to set all corrupted data filed to `null`.

See Table Description

```
desc t_coke_ogn
Name                   Null     Type         
---------------------- -------- ------------ 
BOTTLE_CODE              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
COKE_INFO                            CLOB         
LAST_VERSION_CODE               VARCHAR2(30)
```

See `COKE_INFO` data.

```
 [
  {
    "type": {
      "label": "MIRINDA",
      "code": 15
    },
    "repeatedColumn": {
      "repeatedColumn": {
        "repeatedColumn": "Coke_1633795"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

`repeated_column` above is sometime repeated sometime 10 times and some times 2. I want to set it to `null` like shown below

```
[
  {
    "type": {
      "label": "MIRINDA",
      "code": 15
    },
    "repeatedColumn": null
  }
]
```

Not sure how to progress here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_table()` function together with string functions `regexp_replace()` and `replace()` :

```
SELECT replace(regexp_replace(coke_info, '[[:space:]]*'),rcol,'null') as coke_info
  FROM t_coke_ogn
 CROSS JOIN json_table(coke_info, '$.repeatedColumn[*]'
              COLUMNS (rcol VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$'))
```

**or** in order to update directly :

```
MERGE INTO t_coke_ogn t1
USING 
(
SELECT bottle_code , replace(regexp_replace(coke_info, '[[:space:]]*',''),rcol,'null') 
    as coke_info
  FROM t_coke_ogn
 CROSS JOIN json_table(coke_info, '$.repeatedColumn[*]'
              COLUMNS (rcol VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$'))) t2
   ON (t2.bottle_code = t1.bottle_code)         
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
   SET t1.coke_info = t2.coke_info
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91bb909020b15f5f0a38b18537704f79)</kbd>

Comment: I am getting empty response @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: please have a look at the demo just added @KunalVohra .

Comment: Let me just see.

Comment: I see the demo working perfectly but I still see empty response when I do it through my console. :( Is there a reason you see for that

Comment: Indeed, DB version within the demo is 18, but I also tried within my DB, which has the version  12.1.0.2.0 , without problem.I couldn't understand the issue along with your case @KunalVohra .

Comment: Perhaps I need to increase the precision. not 100 but to 4000 @KunalVohra

Comment: I tried. Same result. Now I am getting bit more confused @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: I changed the REGEX per my real example and did the job.